# Google autocomplete is floating with scroll bar

Tags: css

[image]

I have an input tag and I attached google autocomplete directive to it as mentioned in my below code. So when I start searching for any location, the Google autocomplete has appeared as dropdown (refer the screenshot). The Problem is that when I searched some location and Google autocomplete appeared based on search location, at the same moment I started scrolling the page due to which the Google autocomplete is also floating in the screen with the scroll bar movement (refer the screenshot). How should I stick the autocomplete with the Input tag so that it (Google autocomplete) won't float in the page with scrollbar movement?

```
 .pac-container {

  background-color: #fff;

  position: absolute ;

  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden
 }

.pac-container:after {

  content: "";
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 0;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white2.png);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 104px 16px
  }
```

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete

// Below code for input tag with google autocomplete directive

```
  <div class="white-pannel col-md-5 businessNameCSS">
  <h4 class="pannel-title" ng-repeat="header in vm.businessName" ng-if="header.controlName == 'Header'">
    Business Name
  </h4>

  <div class="form-group"
        ng-class="{ 'has-error':  businessDetailsForm.submitted &&
                                      businessDetailsForm.businessName.$touched &&
                                      businessDetailsForm.businessName.$invalid }"
        ng-repeat="header in vm.businessName"
        ng-if="header.controlName == 'Text_Box'">

    <input type="text"
          id="businessName_ID"
          name="businessName"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="{{header.additionalInfo}}"
          systemrefid="{{header.systemRefId}}"
          autocomplete="on|off"
          ng-disabled="vm.disableCompletePage"
          data-uuid="{{header.uuid}}"
          ng-model="vm.businessDetailsForm.uuid[header.uuid]"

          required
          g-places-autocomplete options="vm.autocompleteOptions">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, and understandable

Comment: Not sure what `.pac-container` tries to select, no such element in the HTML you have shown; but – since it is absolutely positioned, maybe you just need to specify a reference point other than the viewport.

Comment: For .pac-container plz refer this:  https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete